# I would like to calculate this limit: $ \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n)) $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms

I would like to calculate this limit:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n)) $$
but I am a bit lost on how to tackle the logarithm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{n^2-4}{n^2}\right)$, for starters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it helps to express it this way, so you only have to solve a limit without $\ln(x)$: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n)) =  \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln(n^2-4)-\ln(n^2)) $$ $$ =  \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln\big({n^2-4 \over n^2}\big))=  \lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\big(\big({n^2-4 \over n^2}\big)^{n^2+1}\big) =  \ln\big(\lim_{n \to \infty}\big({n^2-4 \over n^2}\big)^{n^2+1}\big)  $$

Comment: going by this, is my next step correct?: $\ln\big(\lim_{n \to \infty}\big({1-4/n^2 \over 1}\big)^{n^2+1}\big)=\ln(1)=0$ ?

Comment: Not quite, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big(1-{4 \over n^2}\big)^{n^2+1} = e^{-4}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how it became $e^{-4}$?

Comment: Well, you can substitute $n^2$ with $m$. Then you have the known limit of  $e^{-4}$. The $+1$ in the exponent does not change the behavoir of the limit, since $O(m+1) = O(m)$.

Comment: wolfram says the result is $-4$. Where could be a problem?

Comment: $e^{-4}$ is the result of the *inner limit*. The limit is surrounded by $\ln(..)$. So the original limit is of course $-4$.

Comment: oh, yeah, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

$2\ln n=\ln(n^2),$

$\implies\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n)=\ln\left(1-\dfrac4{n^2}\right)$

Setting $1/n=h$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\cdot(\ln(n^2-4)-2\ln(n))=-4\cdot\lim_{h\to0}(1+h^2)\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1-4h^2)}{-4h^2}=?$$

Comment: sorry, but the last step seems very complicated to me, for example, why did it become $\lim_{h \to 0}$

Comment: @Mykybo, I've chosen $1/n=h$